# how connect to a shared host with python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a sql file in my shared host that has a user , password.
how can I connect to it ? can I use myscl.connector module ?

Answer (score 0):

#### You could connect to your remote machine using the following code

```
# Connect to MYSQL
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="password"
)
```

To get the hostname from your remote machine you'll have to log into it's command line and insert the following statement :

```
select user();
```

You should get the following output

```
+----------------+
| user()         |
+----------------+
| root@localhost |
+----------------+
```

alternatively you could use the mysql workbench to view its hostname/port.

Comment: my host isn't local. I use this code for localhost and it worked well but in remote host not work

Comment: you change those according to whatever you need..